# Different ChildComponent based on data

Tags: angular, angular-components

How can I change an Component based on data that I get from database?
I'm using something like this: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-portal-tools-z8jmxe?file=app/components/tools/clear-tool/clear-tool.component.ts)
But tools are show depending on user roles. (Database returns which tools, order 
and so on)

There are two ways I can think of how to do this:

**First**
Using `*ngIf` like:

```
<div class="tools-wrapper controls">
  <div class="tools-container">
    <app-tool-menu *ngIf="existsInData('menu')"></app-tool-menu>
    <mat-divider *ngIf="existsInData('menu')"></mat-divider>
    <app-tool-refresh *ngIf="existsInData('refresh')"></app-tool-refresh>
    <app-tool-info *ngIf="existsInData('info')"></app-tool-info>
    <app-tool-edit *ngIf="existsInData('edit')"></app-tool-edit>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is not dynamically enough.

**Second**
Using the `factoryResolver`

```
@Injectable()
export class InjectorService {
  constructor(private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  setRootViewContainerRef(viewContainerRef) {
    this.rootViewContainer = viewContainerRef;
  }

  addDynamicComponents(data: any[]) {
    const component = factory.create(this.rootViewContainer.parentInjector);

    data.forEach((tool) => {
      const toolComponent = this.toolMapping(tool);
      const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(toolComponent);
      this.rootViewContainer.insert(component.hostView);
    });
  }

  toolMapping(tool) {
    const tools = {
      'menu': MenuComponent,
      'refresh': RefreshComponent,
      'info': InfoComponent,
      'edit': EditComponent,
    };
    return tools[tool];
  }
}



@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1> 
    <ng-template #dynamic></ng-template>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'from Angular';

  @ViewChild('dynamic', { read: ViewContainerRef }) 
  viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private service: InjectorService ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.setRootViewContainerRef(this.viewContainerRef);
    this.service.addDynamicComponents(.. data ..);
  }
}
```

Well there is a lot of overhead in this code, like defining a toolMapping or creating a Service for each similar construct I have.

Is there a better and cleaner solution?

Data looks like this (Can be modified if necessary):

```
[
  {type: 'menu', tooltip: '', ...},
  {type: 'divider', tooltip: '',...},
  {type: 'refresh', tooltip: '', ...},
  {type: 'info', tooltip: '',...},
  {type: 'edit', tooltip: '',...},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AngularJS` is possible compile components by only component tag like :
`<comp></comp>` if it comes as string.

But in new `Angular` unfortunately not yet. I watched `ComponentFactoryResolver`, `ngComponentOutlet` API's. They only accept `Type<T>` [resolveComponentFactory](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactoryResolver#resolveComponentFactory)
, where `T` is some Component/Directive... class.

So you can't pass component selector as string.

As a solution types:

- create  `Map<string, any>()`. `key` - type, `any` - component type

  and in template iterate over data:

  ```
  <ng-container  *ngFor="let itm of data">
      <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="someMap.get(itm.type)"> 
      </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  ```
- create method `getComponentType(type: string)`. Some search logic here.
  **template:**

  ```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let itm of data">
      <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="getComponentType(itm.type)">
      </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  ```

Comment: I see there is no way currently without a mapping.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `<ng-container>` with [`ngComponentOutlet`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet)? It's much less verbose than the `ComponentFactoryResolver` solution.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AComponent } from './a.component';
import { BComponent } from './b.component';
import { CComponent } from './c.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <input type="radio" value="A" name="comp" [(ngModel)]="radioValue"> A
    <input type="radio" value="B" name="comp" [(ngModel)]="radioValue"> B
    <input type="radio" value="C" name="comp" [(ngModel)]="radioValue"> C

    <ng-container [ngComponentOutlet]="selected"></ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  radioValue: 'A' | 'B' | 'C';

  get selected() {
    switch (this.radioValue) {
      case 'A': {
        return AComponent
      }
      case 'B': {
        return BComponent
      }
      case 'C': {
        return CComponent
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-87u75c)